# django modelformset_factory is adding a bogus 'id' field to my modelforms, and I'd like it to stop

Tags: django, django-forms

Like the title says, using `modelformset_factory` to generate a set of modelforms, it appears to add an additional select field to each form, labelled `'id'`. I want to stop that.

[**edit:** I have a solution posted below, but it is definitely a hack. If there is a "proper" way to suppress this, I would very much like to know about it. If there isn't, I wouldn't mind finding out if there is a good reason why not.]

Here's the code for the formset:

```
from models import ArticlesTemplate
class ExistingTemplateForm(ModelForm):
    selected = forms.BooleanField(required=False, initial=False, widget=forms.RadioSelect(), label = 'use?')
    class Meta:
        model =  ArticlesTemplate
        exclude = ('template_file', 'organisation_for', 'mime_type', 'id', 'pk',)


ExistingTemplateFormset = modelformset_factory(ArticlesTemplate, extra = 0, form=ExistingTemplateForm)
```

(Note that adding `, exclude=('id',)` to the `modelformset_factory` call does not prevent this field from being added).

This is the html generated by the modelform on its own:

```
In [15]: print i_h.ExistingTemplateForm()
<tr><th><span id="for-id_original_filename-">Original filename:</span></th><td><input id="id_original_filename" type="text" name="original_filename" maxlength="100" /></td></tr>
<tr><th><span id="for-id_tags-">Tags:</span></th><td><input type="text" name="tags" id="id_tags" /><br /><span class="helptext">A comma-separated list of tags.<
/span></td></tr>
<tr id="selected_row" class="selected_row "><th><span id="for-id_selected_0-">use?</span></th><td><ul>

</ul></td></tr>
```

As expected, no `id` field.

This is the html generated by the formset:

```
In [24]: print etf

<input type="hidden" name="form-TOTAL_FORMS" value="1" id="id_form-TOTAL_FORMS" /><input type="hidden" name="form-INITIAL_FORMS" value="1" id="id_form-INITIAL_F
ORMS" /><input type="hidden" name="form-MAX_NUM_FORMS" id="id_form-MAX_NUM_FORMS" />
<tr><th><span id="for-id_form-0-original_filename-">Original filename:</span></th><td><input id="id_form-0-original_filename" type="text" name="form-0-original_
filename" value="FakeExampleCompanyName.docx" maxlength="100" /></td></tr>
<tr><th><span id="for-id_form-0-tags-">Tags:</span></th><td><input type="text" name="form-0-tags" value="&quot;England and Wales&quot;, &quot;Model articles wit
h amendments&quot;, &quot;Private company limited by shares&quot;" id="id_form-0-tags" /><br /><span class="helptext">A comma-separated list of tags.</span></td
></tr>
<tr id="selected_row" class="selected_row "><th><span id="for-id_form-0-selected_0-">use?</span></th><td><ul>

</ul></td></tr>
<tr><th><span id="for-id_form-0-id-">Id:</span></th><td><select name="form-0-id" id="id_form-0-id">
<option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
<option value="1">ArticlesTemplate object</option>
</select></td></tr>
```

As you can see, there is that `select` element right at the end, that I didn't ask for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use form.visible_fields instead.

Eg:

```
            {% for form in formset %}
                {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                    {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
                {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Awesome! I take it this isn't a new feature, either.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I found, and I admit it isn't entirely satisfactory:

```
class ExistingTemplateFormset(modelformset_factory(ArticlesTemplate, extra = 0, form=ExistingTemplateForm)):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ExistingTemplateFormset, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for x in self: x.fields['id'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
```

This is a solution that, to my surprise, didn't work:

```
class ExistingTemplateForm(ModelForm):
    selected = forms.BooleanField(required=False, initial=False, row_renderer = default_renderer, widget=forms.RadioSelect(), label = 'use?')
    id = forms.ModelChoiceField(widget = forms.HiddenInput(), queryset = ArticlesTemplate.objects.all())
    class Meta:
        model =  ArticlesTemplate
        exclude = ('template_file', 'organisation_for', 'mime_type',)
## This __init__ has no effect on the widget used to render id
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ExistingTemplateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['id'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(widget = forms.HiddenInput(), queryset = ArticlesTemplate.objects.all())
        self.fields['id'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no solution for exactly this problem which i have, too. But I have found a workaround:

I render the id-field without label an as hidden field with the tag `{{form.id}}`. The output is for example: `<input id="id_form-0-id" name="form-0-id" type="hidden" value="1" />`

But if you render the formset with tags like `{{ formset }}` or 
    
        {% for form in formset %}
        {{ form }}
        {% endfor %}

You will become a visible label before the id field.

I hope i could help